# If $pth$ term of an A.P is $q$ and its $qth$ is $ p$, show that its $rth$ term is $p+q-r$. What is its $(p+q)th $term?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

**p**$th$,**q**$th$ and **r**$th$ term are $q, p, p+q-r$ respectively.

$a_{p}= a+(p-1)d = q$

$= a+pd-d=q$

$a_{q} = a+(q-1)d = p$

$=a+qd-d=p$

Now for getting common difference we should minus 2nd term from first term that means
**p**$th$ term minus **q**$th$ term. which is

$a_{q}-a_{p}$ $\Rightarrow$ d = 1

But in my book it is given

$a_{p}-a_{q}$

after solving

$\Rightarrow$ $ d = 1$

Now I want to understand the complete answer.

Comment: See alternative, if slightly unorthodox, method in solution posted below!

Answer (score 1):

> Finding the $rth$ term:

$a_{p}= a+(p-1)d = q$ and $a_{q}= a+(q-1)d = p$.

Solving these two you get that $(p-q)d=q-p\implies d=-1$.

Just putting $d=-1$ in 
$a_{p}= a+(p-1)d = q$ yield that $a=p+q-1$.

$a_r= a_(r-1)d=p+q-1+(r-1)\times -1=p+q-r$

> Finding $(p+q)$th term:

$a_{p+q}=a+(p+q-1)d=p+q-1+(p+q-1)\times -1=0$

Comment: And as of the $(p+q)^{th}$ term, it is $a + (p+q-1)d = a + (a)(-1) = 0$

Comment: yes @ShraddheyaShendre, I was adding the same. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @THE LONE WOLF. How did you know that we have to minus $a_{p}-a_{q}$, Why $a_{q}-a_{p}$ not.

Comment: @bappy - It does not matter whether you do $a_p - a_q$ or $a_q - a_p$. Either way you get $d=-1$ as the corresponding $RHS$'s also get swapped accordingly.

Comment: @bappy shraddheya has given a reasonable explaination.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's another method. No need for AP formulas!**

Adding $p$ to the $p$-th term (=$q$) gives $p+q$.
Adding $q$ to the $q$-th term (=$p$) gives $p+q$.

Since the AP is linear we can conclude that adding $n$ to the $n$-th term gives $p+q$.

Hence the $n$-th term of the AP is given by
$$U_n=p+q-n$$

Putting $n=p,q$ results in 
$U_p=q, U_q=p$, as given, and this  confirms the formula above.

Putting $n=r$, we have 
$$\color{red}{U_r=p+q-r}$$

Putting $n=p+q$, we have 
$$\color{red}{U_{p+q}=0}$$